# Fetch an item from the list containing specific test from ansible

Tags: filter, ansible, grep

I need to filter items contain "TEST" in the below mentioned list,

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "TEST_Automation",
        "TEST-LAB",
        "PROD-Common",
        "LAB-IT",
        "TEST-Core",
        "NutanixESX",
        "NutanixLAB",
        "TEST-LaaS",
        "Projects"
    ]
}
```

I use the bellow command to get the above mentioned list:

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ cluster_info.clusters.keys() | list }}"
```

Tried selectattr or lookup but I'm unable to write correct syntax to grep the items containing "TEST". Any suggestion as I use old community version I cannot use items2dict.

Answer (score 1):

`selectattr` doesn't make any sense because you have a simple list of strings (the items don't have attributes). `lookup` makes even less sense because that's for creating generating new information from some sort of query (like reading the lines from a file, or reading an environment variable, etc).

If you want to *select* items from a list based on some sort of criteria, you want the [`select` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.select):

> Filters a sequence of objects by applying a test to each object, and only selecting the objects with the test succeeding.

That would look something like:

```
cluster_info.clusters.keys() | select('match', 'TEST')
```

Here we're using the [`match` test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings), which "succeeds if it finds the pattern at the beginning of the string".

A runnable example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    cluster_info:
      clusters:
        "TEST_Automation": {}
        "TEST-LAB": {}
        "PROD-Common": {}
        "LAB-IT": {}
        "TEST-Core": {}
        "NutanixESX": {}
        "NutanixLAB": {}
        "TEST-LaaS": {}
        "Projects": {}

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ cluster_info.clusters.keys() | select('match', 'TEST') | list }}"
```

The above example outputs:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "TEST_Automation",
        "TEST-LAB",
        "TEST-Core",
        "TEST-LaaS"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Hi, I'm using the ansible version 2.9.27, I'm getting the below error:```ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "<generator object select_or_reject at 0x7f47bd036728>"
```

Comment: For that version, you'll need to stick the `list` filter into the pipeline. I've updated the answer (I'm using 2.12.6, which doesn't require this).

Comment: My apology, I maynot be able to update to the version, even I tried with the syntax including list ```msg: "{{ cluster_info.clusters.keys() | list | select('match', 'TEST') }}"``` I'm getting the same error:```"msg": "<generator object select_or_reject at 0x7f9dc5d33360>"```

Comment: My bad, it was apparently the `select` filter that returns a generator, so: `cluster_info.clusters.keys() | select('match', 'TEST') | list`. I've updated the question and tested the playbook against 2.9.27 to verify that it works.